# Can I get entity relationships dynamically in SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

TargetFramework: netstandard2.0

EntityFrameworkCore: 2.2.6

I have the following code in OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SlotOrder>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => new Guid(v));
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<SlotOrderDetail>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => new Guid(v));

        entity.HasOne<SlotOrder>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SlotOrderId);
    });
}
```

I do not use navigation properties and need to load all relationships of a particular entity in SaveChangesAsync. In my case if the entity is SlotOrder I need to determine that it has a child entity SlotOrderDetail:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var added = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added)
        .Select(t => t.Entity)
        .ToList();

    added.ForEach(entity =>
    {
        if (entity is IAuditable auditable)
        {
            auditable.CreatedAt = utcNow;
            auditable.UpdatedAt = utcNow;
        }

        // var relationships = ...
    });

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Any clue how to do that?

Comment: It's possible to retrieve information about entity foreign keys or referencing foreign keys, but not sure what you can do with that information. *"need to load all relationships"* - load where? Relationships are "loaded" into navigation properties, and you have no navigation properties. W/o navigation properties you basically can't use EF Core related data services, and have to write all that stuff yourself, most likely in a suboptimal way. What you can get is list of [IForeignKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey?view=efcore-3.1)

Comment: @IvanStoev right, as you can see in the code above I specify the relationships using FluentApi and what I need is to get those definitions in SaveChangesAsync. So in my case I am able to determine that SlotOrder entity is a parent of SlotOrderDetail. I would do that via reflection if I had navigation properties, but thats the point - I have no ones. Could you give some more details around IForeignKey you menioned? How can I get a list of IForeignKeys from the EF model for a particular entity type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship metadata is provided by [IForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey?view=efcore-2.2) interface.

Given an [IEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype?view=efcore-2.2), there are two methods that you can use to obtain information for entity relationships - [GetForeignKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.getforeignkeys?view=efcore-2.2) which returns the relationships where the entity is the dependent, and [GetReferencingForeignKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getreferencingforeignkeys?view=efcore-2.2) which return the relationships where the entity is the principal.

In your case, don't select the `.Entity` property, use the `EntityEntry` which gives you access to the `IEntityType` via `Metadata` property, e.g.

```
var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added)
    .ToList();

addedEntries.ForEach(entry =>
{
    if (entry.Entity is IAuditable auditable)
    {
        auditable.CreatedAt = utcNow;
        auditable.UpdatedAt = utcNow;
    }

    var foreignKeys = entry.Metadata.GetForeignKeys();
    var referencingForeignKeys = entry.Metadata.GetReferencingForeignKeys();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do that but I just got another idea, something like this. Create new function to do SaveChanges then load all.

In any class you create you like.

```
public IQueryable<T> CommitLoad<T>() where T : class
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        var list = db.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

        var key = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.FirstOrDefault();
        var foreignkeys = key.GetContainingPrimaryKey().GetReferencingForeignKeys();

        if (foreignkeys.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in foreignkeys)
                list = list.Include<T>(item.DeclaringEntityType.DisplayName());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Any class or page

```
public IQueryable<SlotOrder> GetTest()
    {
        //Save record to table

        //After saving record, savechanges + load all
        var list = CommitLoad<SlotOrder>();

        return list;
    }
```

Here is result screenshot

[image: See this result screenshot]